# Horizontal Recycler View | Useless space between items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I try to make a horizontal recyclerview, and I face a problem: some extra space is created between items.
I've never faced this problem with a vertical recyclerview...

My main fragment, with the recyclerview:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"           
            android:textColor="@color/darkGreen"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"           
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView            
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"            
            android:textColor="@color/darkGreen"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"            
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

My list item, very basic and doesn't take extra space:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:src="@drawable/social"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would be very grateful for your help

Comment: Can you take a screenshot ???

Comment: this link might be useful for you --> https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: fill the image with match parent

Comment: @notTdar It doesn't work...

Comment: Can you take a screenshot ???  Can you take a screenshot ???  Can you take a screenshot ???  Can you take a screenshot ???  Can you take a screenshot ???